# Присвоение класса к элементу через индекс класса

Tags: jquery

Имеется вот такая структура `HTML` + `JQ` кода.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.m\\.catalog\\.personal-card\\.head').click(function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m.catalog.personal-card.block BR(18)" notes="Описание">
                <div class="m.catalog.personal-card.head FS(26)" notes="Название блока">
                    <h3>Описание</h3>
                    <div class="m.catalog.personal-card.btn-view BR(18)"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="m.catalog.personal-card.body" notes="Контент блока">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magni magnam, tempora voluptatibus illum earum aperiam tempore unde cumque temporibus vel perferendis ut error omnis, ratione autem ab quidem tenetur.
                </div>
        </div>
```

JQ Код добавляет класс `active` для класса `m.catalog.personal-card.head`

Вот, как можно сделать что-бы добавлялся класс  `active` для класса `m.catalog.personal-card.body`. Фактически нужно узнать индекс класса `m.catalog.personal-card.head` и присвоить класс `active` для класса `m.catalog.personal-card.body`.

Вот код которые берёт индекс класса при клике:

```
            $('.m\\.catalog\\.personal-card\\.head').click(function() {
                $('.m\\.catalog\\.personal-card\\.head').index( this );
            });
```

Помогите продолжить код. Фактически есть всё (`но это не точно`), но плохо владею JQ - чтобы это все реализовать!

Comment: Note: Точки в классе вместо `_` или `-`, прям плохая идея...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.m\\.catalog\\.personal-card\\.head').click(function() {
    let b = $(this).parent().children('.m\\.catalog\\.personal-card\\.body');
    b.toggleClass('active');
});
```

или

```
$('.m\\.catalog\\.personal-card\\.head').click(function() {
    let b = $(this).next('.m\\.catalog\\.personal-card\\.body');
    b.toggleClass('active');
});
```

или (если после элемента `.head` не будет элементов кроме `.body`)

```
$('.m\\.catalog\\.personal-card\\.head').click(function() {
    let b = $(this).next();
    b.toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: не подскажете ли литературу или источники, для более углубленного изучения JQ ?